# Chrome extension Browser action icon querying

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-automation, browser-action

I am not sure, but is there a way to figure out what browser action icon currently is used?

Maybe i am just stupid, but better to ask than to never know.

Comment: No, as you can see in the documentation there's no such API so your extension will have to remember the icon name in a variable or storage.

Comment: Thank you. Would have been interesting if there was something without running the same code the extension runs.